# How to deal with MinMaxScaler when there is only a single input?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I was working with `MinMaxScaler`. So the following input:

```
data = [[-1, 2], [-0.5, 6], [0, 10], [1, 18]]
```

would be transformed in the range(0,1) as follows:

```
[[ 0.    0.  ]
 [ 0.25  0.25]
 [ 0.5   0.5 ]
 [ 1.    1.  ]]
```

Now how to transform a single input? On passing the single input such as :

```
data = [[1,18]]
```

will transform as follows:

```
[[0.,0.]]
```

The reason being, there is no `Min` and no `Max`, thus scaling to `0`. But what shall I do in cases where all I have is a single input and want to pass this to a  Machine Learning Model (trained after scaling down both inputs and outputs) as input? All the outputs will be the same irrespective of the dissimilarity in the data before scaling. This definitely is not right. What can I do here? Is there some way I can represent a single input as not a series of `0.`?

Here is what I did during the training process:

```
    X_scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
    Y_scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))

    # Scale both training inputs and outputs
    X_scaled_training = X_scaler.fit_transform(X_training)
    Y_scaled_training = Y_scaler.fit_transform(Y_training)

    X_scaled_testing = X_scaler.transform(X_testing)
    Y_scaled_testing = Y_scaler.transform(Y_testing)
```

During the training process I inverted the value from the model as follows to get the final output score:

```
Y_predicted = Y_scaler.inverse_transform(Y_predicted_scaled)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly. If the machine learning model is already trained, you should use the transformation used on the training set, so you should not have this problem

Comment: @FlorianGD How should I pass the single input to the model? They are integer values with some very large numbers.

Comment: @FlorianGD Model is trained but now I have to be in evaluation mode with real world data.

Comment: You could `transform` this input with the MinMaxScaler object created when training

Comment: Too broad. Add context. Usually you fit on training, but transform when doing prediction. Those are sklearns api-names.

Comment: @sascha Don't exactly understand what you mean. I have added a small snippet on how I used `MinMaxScaler` while training the model.

Comment: @FlorianGD Do you mean saving the object for use in different scripts? I have added snippet on how I used `MinMaxScaler` during training. Please let me know, if you need more code/info.

Comment: @SuhailGupta yes, you should reuse all the preprocessing steps you used to train the model on your real world data before prediction

Comment: @FlorianGD Okay but I do not have the intuition of why I should I be reusing the same scaler object / is there another way I could be trying. It will be very helpful if you could have all of this in an answer.

Comment: I'm not near my computer, so I cannot do a proper answer for now. The intuition is that 0 for your model represent a certain value, and if your real world data is beneath this value, you want to tell that to the model

Comment: @FlorianGD This was a big realization.

Comment: @SuhailGupta glad it helped!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few plausible interpretations of what you're asking.

- If you're interested in using a single variable for your **training set**, scaling everything to 0 is a reasonable interpretation. Without some sort of domain knowledge or other sources of information, the best guess you have is simply the average value (or median or whatnot depending on your error function).
- If you're interested in using a single variable for your **test set**, the problem is that you should be using the same min/max scaling that you did for your training data. Since the parameters for that min/max scaling are already pre-determined, your new data will almost certainly not be scaled to 0 (and if it does, that's still the correct choice).

The reason you would want to use the same min/max scaler for your test data (or production data or whatnot) is because for your model to **generalize**, it needs to be operating on the same kind of data as what you trained it on. One way to think about a machine learning model is that it replicates an observed probability distribution. If you use a different min/max scaler (or any other step in your pre-processing) on your test data, then you will be using information about one probability distribution to attempt to predict what is likely a completely different distribution. That usually doesn't work well.

Answer (score 0):

Although the question is already answered, I'll try to give a bit of intuition along with some code. We will use the Boston dataset from sklearn to predict the median value with 2 features with a linear regression and do not care if the model is not so good.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.datasets import load_boston
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

data = load_boston()

X, y = data.data[:,[0, 4]], data.target
```

I selected 2 features to predict the median value of owner-occupied homes in $1000's (target).

For the record, I chose those so as to have a single min value, and they are respectively the per capita crime rate by town, and the nitric oxides concentration (parts per 10 million).

We will build a training set that excludes the minimum values, to see what happens.

```
# The minimum values in each column are in row 0 and 286 respectively
indices = [i for i in range(506) if i != 0 and i != 286]

X_train, y_train = X[indices], y[indices]

preproc = MinMaxScaler()

X_train = preproc.fit_transform(X_train)

lin_model = LinearRegression()

lin_model.fit(X_train, y_train)

Out: LinearRegression(copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True, n_jobs=1, normalize=False)
```

Let's check on a test set with the previously excluded values, compare with the results we would have with a brand new `MinMaxScaler` on those values.

```
X_test = X[[0, 286], :]

X_test_scaled = preproc.transform(X_test)
print(X_test_scaled)

[[-3.07978878e-05  3.09128631e-01]
 [ 1.19032713e-04 -8.29875519e-03]]
```

Notice the negative values on the array above: this will indicate to the model that those values are below the previously seen minimum.

```
expected = y[[0, 286]]
scaled = lin_model.predict(X_test_scaled)
newly_scaled = lin_model.predict(MinMaxScaler().fit_transform(X_test))

print(f"""
target:                         {expected}
with scale from training:       {scaled}
with scale from the new values: {newly_scaled}
"""
)
target:                         [24.  20.1]
with scale from training:       [23.94137825 27.88512316]
with scale from the new values: [15.34941368  3.91320062]
```

Notice also that the values predicted with a new scaler are off by a large amount.

---

Regarding the question with only one value, as you said, we get [0, 0]. This means that any value that you put in the first place, you will get the same prediction every single time.

```
MinMaxScaler().fit_transform(X[0, :].reshape(1, -1)) #reshape is needed when there is a single sample

Out: array([[0., 0.]])

val = X[0, :].reshape(1, -1)
print(f"intital value: {val}")
newly_scaled = MinMaxScaler().fit_transform(val)
print(f"with the new scaler: {newly_scaled}")
print(f"target: {y[0]}")
print(f"prediction: {lin_model.predict(newly_scaled)}")

intital value: [[0.00632 0.538  ]]
with the new scaler: [[0. 0.]]
target: 24.0
prediction: [27.78476671]
```

With another value

```
val = X[161, :].reshape(1, -1)
print(f"intital value: {val}")
newly_scaled = MinMaxScaler().fit_transform(val)
print(f"with the new scaler: {newly_scaled}")
print(f"target: {y[161]}")
print(f"prediction: {lin_model.predict(newly_scaled)}")

intital value: [[1.46336 0.605  ]]
with the new scaler: [[0. 0.]]
target: 50.0
prediction: [27.78476671]
```

So, in a nutshell, you should reuse the preprocessing as it was defined to train the model on your real world data (and on test data, and on validation data). Be wary of scaling only one sample, as you effectively dismiss all information on the input data.